# An outside script to load layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layers

I have been piecing code together from a number of posts to python outside of QGIS that will open a QGIS instance and then load specific data I feed it. I am not to familiar with using the QGIS API commands, so I am a bit lost. I assume that I am not properly pointing to the instance that is being open. Seems like there are a lot of questions revolving around this topic, but I haven't been able to find something up to date (QGIS 3.16) or that uses scripting outside of the QGIS shell.

Any suggestions?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *

app_path = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/bin/qgis-ltr-bin.exe"

def open_app(application_path):
    subprocess.call(application_path)
    
def open_layers():
    qgishome = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/apps/qgis-ltr/"
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgishome, True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/my_shapefile.shp", 'layer', 'ogr')

    ### EDITS ###
    ex = vlayer.extent()
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setExtent(ex)
    ### EDITS ###

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

def main():
    open_app(app_path)
    open_layers()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Class Edits**

With the advice from @J. Monticolo I created a class and defined `self.canvas`, but the same problem occurs. A small window appears and disappears as if the app loads and exits. I'll admit, I have not worked with classes much so I am a bit rusty.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    
    def open_layers(self):
        qgishome = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/apps/qgis-ltr/"
        app = QgsApplication([], True)
        QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgishome, True)
        QgsApplication.initQgis()
        
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/my_shapefile.shp", 'layer', 'ogr')
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        ex = vlayer.extent()
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setExtent(ex)

        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
        self.canvas.show()
    
def main():
    app = Test()
    app.open_layers()
```

Comment: I added the `QgsMapCanvas` (used this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363363/difference-between-iface-mapcanvas-and-qgsmapcanvas) for reference). The code runs without error, but it does not open QGIS.exe and load the layer. That is why I had the `subprocess.call(application_path)`.

Comment: It seems that I need to call `app` somewhere?

Comment: At the end? A small window launched for a fraction of a second and then disappeared. No errors received. Does my `qgishome` variable need to be pointing to an executable?

Comment: Please check edits @J.Monticolo

Comment: I found this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390519/qgsmapcanvas-window-flashes-on-then-disappears) that adds three lines to the end of `open_layers()` that fixes the window from disappearing. But the window that is loaded looks almost like a white terminal that cannot do anything. It is not a QGIS instance.

Comment: `self.app` and `self.vlayer`. Same problem. Even tried `self.ex`.

Comment: It is a QgsMapCanvas instance, inside a Python3 windows (looks like a blank terminal).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I did not make my question clear. I am looking to launch QGIS and then "drag and drop" wanted layers programmatically. This will allow say a user to bypass the need to do it themselves. The user will need to edit the loaded layers. So I am not looking for a "blank canvas" but actually the QGIS GUI.

Comment: If this is going to be too convoluted, then I will have the user do it manually. Just wanted to try automating the process.

Comment: See here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts

Comment: Thanks @J.Monticolo! I found another [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/running-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside) that seems like it touches on a lot of this. I feel that I am falling into the rabbit hole, so I am going to put this project on hold for a bit. Again appreciate the help and feedback!